# How can I make CGI::Session store session data on the server side using Perl?

Tags: perl, session, cgi

Is there any way to get CGI::Session to store the session id in something besides a cookie or a query string?

Comment: Where do you want to store it? You could manually put it into a Javascript variable or a DOM element attribute, but then you also need to make sure it still reaches the server again.

Answer (score 3):

Storing session id in the cookie or in the query string are the only 2 ways HTTP protocol allows to transfer session id on each and every request. If you store it somewhere else, then there is no way for the client and server to know they are working with the same session.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask CGI::Session to persist session data in a database of your choice. For MySQL, you can do it like so:

```
use CGI::Session;
$session = new CGI::Session("driver:MySQL", undef, {Handle=>$dbh});
```

See [CGI::Session::MySql](http://search.cpan.org/~sherzodr/CGI-Session-3.95/Session/MySQL.pm) for details.